Applying global styles in Next.js 14
I am having issues implementing the  style jsx global property with the new the Next.js. In the previous ones you needed to add it into the _app.js file but since this doesn't exist anymore, I figured it is meant to be added in to the layout.tsx file that represents each page but when I do it, I get the following error
'client-only' cannot be imported from a Server Component module. It should only be used from a Client Component.
This is my code

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <style jsx global>
        {`
                    :root {
                        --title: ${header.style.fontFamily};
                        --content: ${paragraph.style.fontFamily};
                        --primary: ${colors.primary};
                        --primary-dark: ${colors.primaryDark};
                        --secondary: ${colors.secondary};
                        --secondary-dark: ${colors.secondaryDark};
            --background: ${colors.background};
            --paragraph: ${colors.paragraph};
                `}
      </style>
      <body>
        <StyledJsxRegistry>{children}</StyledJsxRegistry>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}



Try putting style in dangerouslySetInnerHTML like:
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <style
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                        __html: `
:root {
 ....
}
                    `,
                    }}
                />
            </head>
            <body>
              <StyledJsxRegistry>{children}</StyledJsxRegistry>
            </body>
        </html>
    )

